# Create a recursive object graph from a tuple with Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, anorm

I've got a very simple database table called regions where each region may have a parent region.

```
mysql> describe region;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| region_code   | char(3)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| region_name   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| parent_region | char(3)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now I'd like to hydrate this data to a Scala object graph of case classes that each have a parent of the same type.

```
case class Region(code: String, name: String, parent: Option[Region])
```

I do this with the following code.  It works but it creates duplicate objects which I'd like to avoid if possible.

```
class RegionDB  @Inject() (db: Database) {
  def getAll(): Seq[Region] = {

    Logger.debug("Getting all regions.")
    db.withConnection { implicit conn =>

      val parser = for {
        code <- str("region_code")
        name <- str("region_name")
        parent <- str("parent_region").?
      } yield (code, name, parent)

      val results = SQL("SELECT region_code, region_name, parent_region from region").as(parser.*)

      // TODO: Change this so it doesn't create duplicate records
      def toRegion(record: (String, String, Option[String])): Region = {
        val (code, name, parent) = record
        val parentRecord = parent.map(p => results.find(_._1 == p)).getOrElse(None)
        new Region(code, name, parentRecord.map(toRegion).orElse(None))
      }

      val regions = results map toRegion

      regions.foreach(r => Logger.debug("region: " + r))

      regions
    }
  }
}
```

I know how to do this in the imperative way but not the functional way.  I know there has got to be an expressive way to do this with recursion but I can't seem to figure it out.  Do you know how?  Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte/tree/10m-anorm-tutorial

Comment: Thank you for the link (and cleaning up the code snippet) but that's not quite what I was looking for.  The example shows a hierarchical data structure, not one a recursive one.  None of the cases classes refer to instances of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by restructuring the Region case class so that the parent region is a var and by adding a collection of children. It would be nice to do this without a var but oh well.

```
case class Region(code: String, name: String, subRegions: Seq[Region]){
    var parentRegion: Option[Region] = None
    subRegions.foreach(_.parentRegion = Some(this))
}
```

The recursion is more natural going from the root down.

```
def getAll(): Seq[Region] = {

  Logger.debug("Getting all regions.")
  db.withConnection { implicit conn =>

  val parser = for {
    code <- str("region_code")
    name <- str("region_name")
    parent <- str("parent_region").?
  } yield (code, name, parent)

  val results = SQL("SELECT region_code, region_name, parent_region from region").as(parser.*)

  def toRegion(record: (String, String, Option[String])): Region = {
    val (regionCode, name, parent) = record
    val children = results.filter(_._3 == Some(regionCode)).map(toRegion)
      Region(regionCode, name, children)
    }

    val rootRegions = results filter(_._3 == None) map toRegion

    rootRegions.foreach(r => Logger.debug("region: " + r))

    rootRegions
  }
}
```